# Programatically add config section to App.config during upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, config, app-config, configurationmanager

I want to be able to add a default `IdMapping` section to the `App.config` if one is missing at runtime. This may happen if they upgrade the application. I need new configuration to have a default in the file.

**App.Config :**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="IdMapping" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PortNumber" value="10001" />
  </appSettings>

  <IdMapping>
    <add key="000810140" value="116" />
    <add key="2" value="117" />
  </IdMapping>
</configuration>
```

I am then reading this in my code like this:

```
var SectionData = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("IdMapping") as NameValueCollection;
```

Is there an easy way to add the `configSections` part and the `IdMapping` part programatically?

Comment: Usually you don't have write access to the config file at runtime. Depending on how you deploy your app, this could be a task perfomred by the setup of a separate configuration step with administrative permissions.

Comment: @KlausGütter Ultimately i would be running this during the upgrade process where the user will have admin rights.

Comment: Well, the config file is just XML and you can use any XML writer to modify it (I prefer  LINQ to XML but this is a matter of taste)